What should we do about the "learning" tag?
The learning tag has no usage guidance, and seems to be a bit ambiguous or at least too general. Here are a few examples of questions using it:

Bayesian Learning: Finding the variance of noise
Machine learning algorithm for finding most similar entries in dataset
Convergence under large set of learning rates
Why are statistics textbook questions so frequently totally artificial?
Is this non-mathematical interpretation of cause-specific vs subdistribution hazards sensible?

I think that more specific tags already cover the subjects this tag could cover:

self-study or possibly references for the case of students or other people learning about statistics;
teaching for questions about teaching stats;
for statistical learning there are machine-learning, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning and a plethora of other "xxxx-learning" tags.

What should we do about this tag?
My preference would be to simply retire it. However I don't know if it is really possible, and even if it is, maybe there are more sensible options that I didn't consider.

This tag is only used 35 times, so no problem getting rid of it, a few a day

@kjetilbhalvorsen A diamond mod can’t just delete the tag across all of CV?

@Dave: No, only SE employees can do that. We have never asked for it, as far as I know. We have removed manually far more than 35, though. I believe Sycorax has already started ,,,

@kjetilbhalvorsen, if getting rid of it is the unanimous stance, you should make this an answer.

We should get rid of it, some have already started. I can see no arguments against it!

+1. I agree the tag has been an old relic of the past and is not useful anymore.

Removed now!!!!!
